# Workaround of GAE's 30 subqueries limitation

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm writing a news application and I want let my users choose their favourite news sources from a list that contains dozens (~60) of sources(Guardian,Times,...). I have a News entity that contains an indexed property "source" and I'm looking for an approach that will let me bypass the limitation of 30 subqueries imposed by App Engine that prevents me for using the IN and EQUALS filters to get all the news that belongs to a big list of sources.

is there any workaround for this limitation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Remember that indexes are expensive - they take a lot of space and multiply the write costs.

I would use a different design. Instead of 60 subqueries (and what happens if your list of sources grows to 500?) I would make the source property unindexed. Then I would load a list of all the latest news and keep it in Memcache. If you lose it, you can always reload it. You can also easily add more items to this list as news come in. You can also split this list into chunks based on time.

Now as users make their calls, you can easily filter this list in memory. Depending on your usage volume, this design will be dozens - or thousands - of times cheaper and work much faster. The biggest difference is that instead of reading the same entities over and over for each user request, you will read them once and serve thousands of requests before you need to read them again.

Comment: Thank you @Andrei The list of sources may grow justly to hundreds of sources after going regional. I'm not sure that the design you proposed is optimal for the specs of my application like infinite scrolling and complexe filtering (most rated, viewed, commented news that belong to a specific bunch of sources) I don't want to do all this  on my own. Moreover I've already implemented a cache layer, server and client side to minimize querying the datastore.

Comment: Actually, these requirements make this design even more attractive. As long as you keep the latest news list in Memcache, you avoid querying the database with a unique combination of search criteria for every user.

Answer (score 0):

With 60 sources, if the user wants `N > 30` of them, you can split the interaction into 2 queries (one for 30, the second one for the rest) and merge the results yourself.  There are practical limits since you don't want to end up with an unbound number of queries, of course, but this should scale up to well above your current 60 sources w/o too many issues.

E.g, in Python, to generate a list of queries:

```
def many_source_queries(sources):
    queries = []
    for i in range(0, len(sources), 30):
        queries.append(News.source.IN(sources[i:i+30]))
    return queries
```

then to merge the multiple queries' results there are of course many approaches, but a simplistic one where you just fetch everything into a list is rather trivial:

```
def fetch_many_queries(queries):
    return [x for q in queries for x in q.fetch()]
```

Of course, you can add filters, ordering (and do a `heapq.merge` of the streams to keep resulting order), etc, etc.  I'm just addressing the "30 subqueries limitation".

Added: this only scales up to a point (esp. in terms of number of sources desired in a query).  For example, if entities can have (say) 600 different sources, and a query wants 300 of them, you're going to get about half the datastore returned to you (if the number of news per source is roughly uniform), and it makes no sense to make 10 separate queries for the purpose.

IOW, as I wrote, above "There are practical limits since you don't want to end up with an unbound number of queries".  On detecting a query for more than some threshold N of sources (a large fraction of the store's contents) I'd rather make a single query w/o the source filter, and selectively ignore entities with "wrong sources" at app level).

So in this case I'd take a different approach, e.g...:

```
import itertools as it

def supermany_source_queries(sources):
    return News.query(), set(sources)

def next_up_to_n(n, news_query, sources_set):
    def goodnews(news): return news.source in sources_set
    while True:
        page = list(it.islice(it.ifilter(goodnews, news_query), n))
        if not page: break
        yield page
```

Here, the main-line code would first call

```
q, ss = supermany_source_queries(sources)
```

then prepare the exact query `eq` from `q` with whatever `.filter` and/or `.order` may be required, and then loop, e.g

```
for onepage in next_up_to_n(pagesize, eq, ss):
    deal_with_page(onepage)
```

Of course this could be factored up in several different ways (probably best with a custom class, able to take a different tack depending on the number of sources being asked for), but once again I'm trying to highlight the general idea, i.e...: rather than using a huge number of separate queries for hundreds of sources, when you're getting a large fraction of the datastore back as a result anyway, use a single query (so resign yourself to getting up to all of the datastore instead of, say, half of it, depending of course on other filters and possible early termination in `deal_with_page`), and use iteration and selection at the application level (with `itertools` &c) to ignore entities not actually of interest.

Comment: Thank you @alex the list may grow to hundreds of sources in the future, do you maintain your approach to query the data store with hundreds of filters, Is there a better approach for this configuration?

Comment: @Hakim, no, if a typical query requires (say) 300 sources, turning it into 10 hits on the datastore becomes rather excessive (it matters much less how many sources are in the entities, much more how many are in the queries); as I wrote, "There are practical limits since you don't want to end up with an unbound number of queries".  On detecting a query for more than some threshold N of sources (a big fraction of the store's contents) I'd rather make a single query w/o the source filter and selectively ignore entities with "wrong sources" at app level).  Hmmm, I'll edit the A to add this.